# Why is logical not after an addition syntactically invalid?

Tags: python, parsing, language-lawyer

Today, I noticed that `not True + 5` is syntactically valid but `5 + not True` isn't.
The syntax error points to the first character of not, as if the operator couldn't be used here. However, `5 + (not True)` works, which leads me to believe it is a parser issue.

Are there any reasons for this error?

- Is it a design decision taken by the language?
- Is it is a parser error, or a behaviour not defined by the language's rules?

I couldn't find any resources concerning this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to look at the [Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) to see why `not True + 5` is syntactically (though not semantically) valid while `5 + not True` is a parse error. Here are the most relevant portions:

###### Relevant grammar rules

```
inversion:
    | 'not' inversion 
    | comparison

comparison:
    | bitwise_or
bitwise_or:
    | bitwise_xor
bitwise_xor:
    | bitwise_and
bitwise_and:
    | shift_expr
shift_expr:
    | sum

sum:
    | sum '+' term 
    | term
```

The order of these rules matches precedence of the various operators involved, from lowest precedence to highest. `'not' inversion` is listed before `sum '+' term` because the `not` operator has lower precedence than `+`.

`not <expr>` is parsed as an *inversion*. Reading top-down following the chain of derivations, you can see that an *inversion* could be a *sum*. This means that `not True + 5` can be parsed as the `not` operator followed by an operand of `True + 5`.

###### Parse tree for `not True + 5`

```
inversion
│       │
'not'   inversion
        │
        comparison
        │
        bitwise_or
        │
        bitwise_xor
        │
        bitwise_and
        │
        shift_expr
        │
        sum
        │
        sum '+' term
        │       │
        term    '5'
        │
        'True'
```

On the other hand if you have `5 + not True` there is no way to construct a parse tree. If you tried, `5 + not True` would be parsed as `sum '+' term`. The left side is fine: `5` can be parsed as a *sum*. There's no valid parse for the right side, though: `not True` is not a *term*.

###### Failed parse tree for `5 + not True`

```
sum ─┬────┐
│    │    │
sum  '+'  term
│         │
term      <error: no derivation for 'not' 'True'>
│
'5'
```

NB: The only way to work back "up" the grammar is to add parentheses. `not True` is not a *term*, but `(not True)` with parentheses is. `5 + (not True)` is syntactically valid. Of course, it's still semantically invalid. But hey, if you don't care about semantics the parser won't stop you.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you very much, the relevant parse trees help a lot to understand the problem. So it is a grammar shortcoming

Answer (score 3):

It's an operator precedence issue; see e.g. [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in the documentation. `+` binds more tightly than `not`, so this:

```
not True + 5
```

Is equivalent to:

```
not (True + 5)
```

And `True` evaluates as `1` in this case (so you get `True + 5 == 6`, and `not 6 == False`). On the other hand:

```
5 + not True
```

Is:

```
(5 + not) True
```

Which doesn't make any sense. You would need to explicitly write:

```
5 + (not True)
```

(Which would equal `5`, since `not True` is `False` and `False` evaluates to `0`.)

Comment: It makes more sense now. So the operators only look at directly adjacent tokens?

Comment: Nitpick: `(5 + not) True` isn't how a parser would parse that line. It's unambiguously `5 + (not True)` -- there's no other way to parse it. The reason it's invalid is because the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) simply doesn't allow it: addition is with *terms*, `not True` is an *inversion*, and there's no derivation from *term* to *inversion* (unless the *inversion* is parenthesized).

Comment: "So the operators only look at directly adjacent tokens?" I'm not sure I'd phrase it that way? Operators are typically only unary (take a single argument, like `not`) or binary (take two arguments, like `+`). There's no operator that's going to do some sort of "lookahead" beyond it's immediate arguments.

Comment: In support of what @john said, note that `2**-10` is accepted by the Python parser, even though the fact that `-2**10` is `-1024` demonstrates that `**` binds more tightly than unary minus.

Comment: @JohnKugelman would you mind expanding your comment in an answer? It's very different from what larsks proposed, and matches python's grammar specification https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

Comment: Or if you'd like to make an edit here, feel free (or suggest different wording).

Comment: @rici this is a very interesting example, and so I'm afraid precedence isn't the issue here, but the language's grammar. I will remove the acceptation mark from this answer

Comment: @sho: there's lots of misunderstanding about what "precedence" actually means, and I don't know if there is even a formal definition. The precedence relations used in operator precedence parsing do not create a partial ordering, much less a total ordering, because they are not transitive. But I think that what John says about unambiguity is key: precedence cannot make an ungrammatical sentence grammatical; it is used to disambiguate between two or more possible parses of a valid sentence.